# Can I allow preconditions on the argument to a higher-order function in Dafny?

Tags: dafny

Is there a way to say that a higher-order function permits preconditions on the function it takes as an argument?

Here's the concrete situation I'm trying to solve. I wrote this function for filtering items in a `seq` based on a predicate:

```
function method filterSeq<T>(s: seq<T>, fn: T -> bool): seq<T>
  ensures forall i | 0 <= i < |filterSeq(s, fn)| :: fn(filterSeq(s, fn)[i]) == true
  ensures forall i | 0 <= i < |filterSeq(s, fn)| :: filterSeq(s, fn)[i] in s
  ensures forall i | 0 <= i < |s| :: fn(s[i]) ==> s[i] in filterSeq(s, fn)
  {
    if |s| == 0 then [] else (
      if fn(s[0]) then [s[0]] + filterSeq(s[1..], fn) else filterSeq(s[1..], fn)
    )
  }
```

This covers the postconditions I care about, but doesn't say anything about the argument to `fn`. I want to say that for any property which holds for all `T` in `s`, this property is permitted as a precondition on `fn`.

The problem that lead me to this was an attempt to filter a sequence containing other sequences:

```
var sequences := [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]];
assert forall i | 0 <= i < |sequences| :: |sequences[i]| == 3;

var result := filterSeq(sequences, sequence => sequence[0] == 4);
```

When I attempt this, I get an error on `sequence[0]`, which says `index out of range`. Fair enough, I try to add a precondition to the lambda:

```
var sequences := [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]];

assert forall i | 0 <= i < |sequences| :: |sequences[i]| == 3;

var result := filterSeq(sequences,
  sequence requires |sequence| == 3 => sequence[0] == 4);
```

Now I get the error `value does not satisfy the subset constraints of 'seq<int> -> bool' (possible cause: it may be partial or have read effects)` on the lambda argument. This also makes sense, I'm passing a partial function where I wrote the type signature for a non-partial one.

My question is: How do I change `filterSeq` to allow this? Can I somehow write it so that it will work with arbitrary preconditions, or will I have to write a separate `filterSeqOfSequences` method to cover this specific use-case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Great question. The answer is yes. You need to use Dafny's notion of partial functions, which are written with a doubly-dashed arrow like `T --> bool`. If `f` has this type, then `f.requires` is its precondition. (In fact, you can think of the total function type `T -> bool` as a special case of `T --> bool` where `f.requires` is true for all values of type `T`.)

Here is one way to rewrite your higher-order function to accept a partial function as an argument:

```
function method filterSeq<T>(s: seq<T>, fn: T --> bool): seq<T>
  requires forall x | x in s :: fn.requires(x)        // ***
  ensures forall x | x in filterSeq(s, fn) :: x in s  // ***
  ensures forall i | 0 <= i < |filterSeq(s, fn)| :: fn(filterSeq(s, fn)[i]) == true
  ensures forall i | 0 <= i < |filterSeq(s, fn)| :: filterSeq(s, fn)[i] in s
  ensures forall i | 0 <= i < |s| :: fn(s[i]) ==> s[i] in filterSeq(s, fn)
{
  if |s| == 0
  then []
  else if fn(s[0]) 
  then [s[0]] + filterSeq(s[1..], fn) 
  else filterSeq(s[1..], fn)
}

method Test()
{
  var sequences := [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]];

  assert forall i | 0 <= i < |sequences| :: |sequences[i]| == 3;

  var result := filterSeq(sequences,
    sequence requires |sequence| == 3 => sequence[0] == 4);
}
```

I just made two changes to your code, marked by `***`.

First is the new precondition on `filterSeq` that you already mentioned in your question that requires that `fn.requires` holds on all elements of `s`. Second, we also need one new technical postcondition that guarantees the output of `filterSeq` is a subset of its input. This is needed to ensure the well formedness of the other postconditions, which try to call `fn` on elements of the output.

The `Test` method does not change at all. It just works with the new version of `filterSeq`.

Comment: Thank you! With some experimenting, I found that `~>` also allows `reads` clauses, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to make this work with `~>`. Is it possible? The problem I'm running into seems to be that for a function `fn` defined with `-->`, `fn.requires()` is a total function, but if `fn` is defined with `~>` then `fn.reads()` is a partial function. When I try to apply `fn.reads()`, I need permission to read what `fn.reads()` reads, and I'm stuck in a loop. I hoped to make a function recursively refer to its own `.reads()` method, but that doesn't seem to be allowed.

Comment: Yes, can you either make a new question or edit your question with an example Test method that you are trying to get to work with a `~>` function?

Comment: I actually found the solution while trying to type up a comprehensive explanation of the errors that I encountered. It looks like the correct thing to do was to add the clause `reads fn.reads` to `filterSeq`. The errors I saw previously came from me trying to call `fn.reads(x)` with some argument.